# GPUImageView rendering Blank after Scroll in ListView Android

Tags: android, android-gpuimageview

I am using `GPUImageView` component from **[android-gpuimage](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage)** Library for displaying Images (with filtered applied on them) in my `ListView`.

The Images are being loaded perfectly with filters for the First time in my `ListView` but when i scroll down the `ListView`, all the Scrolled Cells are displayed Blank.

Here is the code of the `getView(...)` method of my custom `BaseAdapter` :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convert_view, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(convert_view == null)
    {
        if(inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convert_view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.filter_item , null);

    }

    TextView thumb_file_name_tv = (TextView) convert_view.findViewById(R.id.filter_item_thumb_tv);

    GPUImageView thumb_giv = (GPUImageView) convert_view.findViewById(R.id.filter_item_thumb_giv);

    Log.d(TAG, "Image Uri = "+imageUri);

    thumb_file_name_tv.setText(""+filterNames.get(position).toString().trim());

    thumb_giv.setFilter(new GPUImageSepiaFilter());

    thumb_giv.setImage(imageUri); // this loads image on the current thread, should be run in a thread

    thumb_giv.requestRender();

    return convert_view;

}
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong here ? 
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Any clue, what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while since I used that library, but from what I remember, if you change the image in the view, you need to call `deleteImage()` before settings the new image. 
Try calling that method before calling `setImage()` You might need to check if the view has an image present before you can call `deleteImage()` or it might throw an error.

**Edit :**

Add the following methods to the `GPUImageView.java` class of the android-gpuImage library :

```
public void deleteImage() 
{
 mGPUImage.deleteImage(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i am trying this solution now.

Comment: There is no Method such as `deleteImage()` in the `GPUImageView`, but there is a similar method that is  `deleteDrawingCache()` and after using it, the `GPUImageView` is always rendering Blank.

Comment: Sorry, I added that one myself and forgot to mention that. In the GPUImageView class, add the following method: public void deleteImage()
    {
     mGPUImage.deleteImage();
    }

Answer (score 1):

With the new version of GPUImage the deleteImage () method does not exist, I do the following and it worked perfectly.

```
@BindView(R.id.editor)
GPUImageView mEditor;
```

Inside the OnClick that changes the bitmap of the image, do the following:

```
mEditor.getGPUImage().deleteImage();
mEditor.setImage(newBitmap);
```

In this way I delete the previous Bitmap and I can apply the new Bitmap without any problem.